# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException ImmutableList.remove when i didn't use ImmutableList

Tags: java, list, immutability, java-stream

I have this code

```
    final List<String> connectedIds = getConnectedDevices();
    final List<Device> allDbDevicesAsList = getAllDbDevicesAsList();

    List<Device> connectedDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < allDbDevicesAsList.size(); i++) {
        int size = connectedIds.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            final Device currentDevice = allDbDevicesAsList.get(i);
            if(currentDevice.uuid == connectedIds.get(j))
            {
                connectedDevices.add(currentDevice);
                connectedIds.remove(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and I get this exception, even thought I don't use ImmutableList

and I dug into all the methods calls of `getConnectedDevices()`

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.remove(ImmutableList.java:479)
    at com.waze.automation.client.services.web.lib.devices.DevicesServiceLocal.getDevices(DevicesServiceLocal.java:66)
    at com.waze.mobileautomation.devices.DevicesServiceLocalTest.testGetAvailableDevices_returnsOnly(DevicesServiceLocalTest.java:194)
```

using this code will gain same intersection logic, but is less efficient.

```
    List<Device> connectedDevices = allDbDevicesAsList.stream()
            .filter(item -> connectedIds.contains(item.uuid))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How would you re-write the intersection code?

why do i get this error anyways?

Comment: It looks like `getConnectedDevices()` is returning an `ImmutableList`.

Comment: and I dug into all the methods calls of `getConnectedDevices()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of the connected device id `List`. This copy will be mutable.

```
List<String> connectedIds = new ArrayList<String>(getConnectedDevices());
List<Device> allDbDevicesAsList = getAllDbDevicesAsList();

List<Device> connectedDevices = new ArrayList<Device>();

for (int i = 0; i < allDbDevicesAsList.size(); i++) {
    Device currentDevice = allDbDevicesAsList.get(i);
    boolean removed = connectedIds.remove(currentDevice.uuid);
    if (removed) {
        connectedDevices.add(currentDevice);
    }
}
```

PS: The id's collection should be a `Set` instead of a list. E.g.

```
Set<String> connectedIds = new HashSet<String>(getConnectedDevices());
```

Comment: but how can it be immutable from the first place? as then it would have to have casting from immutable list to mutable one. and I searched all over. there is none

Comment: @EladBenda why do you think `getConnectedDevices()` can't return an `ImmutableList`?

Comment: I see it signature `private List<String> getConnectedDevices() {`

Comment: @EladBenda Yes and this means that it returns a `List<String>`. You can not be sure which `List` impementation is returned.E.g it can be an `ArrayList`, a `LinkedList`, a `Vector`, an `ImmutableList` or even a `Stack`. All of these classes implement `List`. The only thing you can be sure is that it is a `List` and the client code should only rely on that.

Comment: @EladBenda But one thing confuses me. You say that the method is `private`. Did you implement it? If so why don't you return another list. If not how can you access the method from your code?

Comment: Intellij de-vompliation. How come it makes any sense?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the list of device IDs from the getConnectedDevices() method to a new ArrayList:

```
 final List<String> connectedIds = new ArrayList<>(getConnectedDevices());
```

That will copy all values from the ImmutableList into an ArrayList from which you can remove items.

The example you have provided using streams look much more concise and understandable. Unless it has a confirmed performance impact that is not acceptable, it would look like the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You might encounter an "UnsupportedOperationException" when you're not intentionally using an immutable list due to certain methods like List.of(object1, object2, ...) or Arrays.asList(...). These methods produce fixed-size lists, which can give the illusion of mutability. If you inadvertently modify a list created using these methods, it will result in the "UnsupportedOperationException" because the lists themselves are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

From the java doc,  it says. it doesn't guarantee about the mutability.

```
public static <T> Collector<T,?,List<T>> toList()
```

Returns a Collector that accumulates the input elements into a new List. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; if more control over the returned List is required, use toCollection(Supplier).
Type Parameters:
T - the type of the input elements
Returns:
a Collector which collects all the input elements into a List, in encounter order.

You can try printing the type of list returned by getConnectedDevices().